# Outputting CLI response on MacOS if one of the response criteria is met

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, terminal, exiftool

I am currently using a command line utility on MacOS (Sierra) called [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). There are a number of ways to run this CLI however in essence, you point the interface at a file and it returns information about a file. In order to limit the amount of information returned, you can simply add arguments to it.

At the moment, here is what I'm trying to achieve in pseudocode:-

Run 'exiftool' against a specific image file. If the 'Megapixels' value > 0 then return 'filename', 'OriginalDate' and 'Megapixels'.

The command to return 'filename' and 'OriginalDate' and 'Megapixels' is simply:-

```
exiftool -filename -OriginalData -Megapixels myphotograph.jpeg
```

How do I however check the Megapixels value before returning all three values? So in essence, I want to run the exiftool CLI against myphotograph.jpeg and if the Megapixels value (argument) is greater than 0, I want it to return that value and the additional two? The output will ultimately be output to a .csv file.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
`exiftool -if '$Megapixels>1' -filename -DateTimeOriginal -Megapixels -cv FileOrDir`

I changed it to greater than 1 since all images are going to have a size greater than 0 as long as there is some image data.  For example, I have an 8x8 image that shows up as 0.000064 megapixels.  All you have to do is change the 1 to whatever number you want to limit your selection by.

I'm assuming you actually meant `DateTimeOriginal` and not `OriginalDate` or `OriginalData`.  Exiftool only recognizes `OriginalDate` as a tag for it's own [MIE format](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/MIE.html#Doc), where it's mapped to `DateTimeOriginal` anyway.

Add `-r` if you want to recurse into subdirectories.

You can add `-csv >/path/to/file.csv` if you want to directly generate a csv file.  This will add an extra column at the start containing the full source path and filename.  You can also look into the [`-p`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#str) option to roll your own csv format.

Answer (score 2):

@StarGeek's answer is more elegant, and portable to Windows, but I have done it with `awk` now and might as well share it:

```
exiftool image.jpg | awk -F': ' '
   /^Create Date/{d=$2}
   /^Megapixels/ {m=$2}
   /^File Name/  {n=$2}
   END{ if(m>0)print n,m,d }' OFS=','
```

**Output**

```
image.jpg,8.0,2015:08:16 14:39:45.275
```